# Elliptically polarized plane wave - expressions for transmitted and reflected fields for brewster angle of incidence between air and glass

Tags: optics

Consider an elliptically polarized plane wave of the form

\$̅_=((sin(_)̂−cos(_)̂)+2^{/4}̂)^{−̅ \cdot ̅+}\$

impinging from air (n=1) on a half space of glass (n=1.5), as in the attached figure. I am trying to find the transmitted and reflected fields if the angle of incidence is the Brewster angle.

First, for the reflected wave, as the angle of incidence is the Brewster angle then the Fresnel factor \$r_{||}\$ would be zero.

Hence, I figured:

\$E_r=r_\bot \cdot ((sin(_)̂−cos(_)̂)+2^{/4}̂)^{−k_i(xsin(_)-ycos(_))+)}\$

where \$r_\bot =(cos(_)-1.5cos(_t))/(cos(_)+1.5cos(_t)), k_1=\omega/c, _t=sin^{-1}(2/3sin(_))\$

Yet I am quite certain the above expression for \$E_r\$ is wrong.

Moving on to finding the transmitted field:

\$t_{||}=2cos(_)/(cos(_t)+1.5cos(_)), t_\bot =2cos(_)/(cos(_b)+1.5cos(_t))\$

Hence, the transmitted field should be of the form:

\$E_t=e^{i \omega t}((sin(_)̂−cos(_)̂)+2^{/4}̂) \cdot ^{−k_t(xsin(_t)+ycos(_t))}[t_\bot + t_{||} \cdot (̂cos(_t)-̂sin(_t))]\$

where \$k_t=1.5 \omega/c\$

Here again I am quite convinced there is a mistake, which I am not sure how to fix.

[image]

Comment: Are \$Cos\$ and \$cos\$ and \$\cos\$ different functions? also, I think this might be better of on Physics.SE

Comment: @MarcusMüller They are one and the same. I have now corrected that.

Comment: How do I ask this question on Physics.SE?

Comment: Can you correct typography in your question, it's hard to read? Then we can take a closer look.